# PVector.random2D() issue

Tags: java, processing

Trying to return a PVector if the position of my particle(the class) is on the edges. This prints the error "The method must return a result of type PVector"

```
PVector edges() {
if (pos.x < 0 + 10 || pos.x > width - 10 || pos.y > 0 +10 || pos.y < height - 10) {
    return PVector.random2D();
 }
}
```

Comment: what happens if `pos` isn't outside of bounds ? maybe return `pos` instead ?

Comment: im trying to return a random vector to apply a force to the particle which leaves the boundaries!

Comment: `PVector edges() {
if (pos.x < 0 + 10 || pos.x > width - 10 || pos.y > 0 +10 || pos.y < height - 10) {
    return PVector.random2D();
 }else return pos;
}` is what I meant ;)

Comment: that worked brilliantly!! thank you very much!

Comment: I've added the comment as an answer for easier future reference. If it was helpful feel free to vote/mark ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function doesn't handle else branch of your edge test, in which case the position returned should probably be the same one:

```
PVector edges() {
if (pos.x < 0 + 10 || pos.x > width - 10 || pos.y > 0 +10 || pos.y < height - 10) {
    return PVector.random2D();
 }else{
    return pos;
 }
}
```